# PHP task queue creation sample (google app engine)

Tags: google-app-engine

I cannot seem to figure out how I can create a Task for a certain task queue, everything I tried failed and the task does not show up in the queue.

Any suggestions or php sample?

Edit: source code from comment.

```
$task = new PushTask(
    '/workers/worker1.php',
    ['var1' => 'this is one', 'var2' => $seconds],
    ['delay_seconds' => $seconds]
);
$queue = new PushQueue('notify');
$queue->addTasks([$task]);
```

Comment: Please inform what exctaly you have tried.Paste any code segments. That will help us.

Comment: Also, make sure you've defined and uploaded a queue.yaml file defining your custom queue.

Answer (score 0):

Try following [Using Push Queues in PHP](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/taskqueue/overview-push) in a separate project.  If you've been having problems there may be an unwanted interaction with the rest of your software.  Also, if the simple example fails you can add its source code to the question here for discussion.

Edit: Thanks for adding the source code.  That leads to two suggestions.  First, the [PushTask documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/taskqueue/overview-push) packs all the optional parameters into a single array. Your PushTask call passes two arrays, which might not work properly.  Therefore combine the parameters into a single array.  Second, the [queue.yaml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/queue) file requested by Amy U. is still absent, so it could be lacking an entry that looks like `- name: notify`.  Could you show that file too?

Comment: Ok, the problem is that my task runs but I cannot see it in any task queue called 'notify'. Below the code:

$task = new PushTask('/workers/worker1.php', ['var1' => 'this is one', 'var2' => $seconds],['delay_seconds' => $seconds]);
 $queue = new PushQueue('notify');
 $queue->addTasks([$task])

Comment: Your task is probably being run by the default queue that has no name.  Rather post the above source code by editing the question, and use the layout options to show it as multiple lines.  Also show that your queue.yaml file is structured according to [PHP Task Queue Configuration](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/queue).

Comment: Layout options? Where?

Pretty annoying the Google sample does not work. Below code show i'm trying to add to queue "notify". The task does not show up anywhere.

$task = new PushTask('/workers/worker1.php', ['var1' => 'this is one', 'var2' => $seconds],['delay_seconds' => $seconds]);
$queue = new PushQueue('notify');
$queue->addTasks([$task])